# Enable code coverage for Jest tests in jest-html-reporter/Istanbul

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, istanbul

I am using [jest-html-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-html-reporter) to generate an HTML report for my tests. The report shows which tests failed and which passed, but doesn't show any information regarding code coverage. I want to have stats like lines covered, statements covered, etc. How can I achieve this?

The project I am working on is based on `create-react-app`, and I have the following configuration in my `package.json`:

```
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!src/assets/**/*.js",
      "!src/routes/index.js",
      "!src/index.js"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 69,
        "functions": 70,
        "lines": 70,
        "statements": 70
      }
    }
  }

"scripts": {
    "test-coverage": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --no-cache --verbose --coverage --reporters=default --reporters=jest-html-reporter",
}
```

I can also use another reporter like `istanbul`, but I couldn't configure it to generate the required html test report.

Comment: The configuration seems to be correct but I feel istanbul can be used for test coverage.

Answer (score 2):

Html report for the test can be generated by Istanbul by simply configuring the package.json file since it comes automatically integrated with Jest

In the Script section of the Package.json just add these two lines :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
  }
```

Save the project and run below commands in the terminal :

Yarn test : to generate coverage in terminal or Yarn test-coverage to generate report.

When Yarn test-coverage is run "COVERAGE" folder is created in the Project directory with the HTML Report in Coverage > Icov-report >index.html

[image]